# Unique URL for each MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, unique

I have the below code and cant make it work to save my life.  It just needs to have one of 3 links depending on which department it is from.  If department = 1 then URL1.com and so on.

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost","dfasrgasdg","asdgasdgasdg") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("asdgasdgash") or die(mysql_error());


// Get all the data from the "example" table
$album = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery_albums WHERE draft = 0 ORDER BY gallery_id DESC
LIMIT 0,3") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
    while($album1 = mysql_fetch_array( $album )) {


if ($album1['department_id'] == '1'); {
$albumURL = "http://ufire.sabinalcanyon.org/gallery.php?gallery_id=".$album1['gallery_id'];
}
if ($album1['department_id'] == '2'); {
$albumURL = "http://ems.sabinalcanyon.org/gallery.php?gallery_id=".$album1['gallery_id'];
}
if ($album1['department_id'] == '3'); {
$albumURL = "http://vfire.sabinalcanyon.org/gallery.php?gallery_id=".$album1['gallery_id'];
}   

echo "
<li class=\"clearfix\">
<a href=\"".$albumURL."\" class=\"thumbnail\">
<img src=\"".$album1['poster_image']."\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\" alt=\"\" />
</a>
<a href=\"".$albumURL."\" class=\"entry-title\">".$album1['title']."</a>
<div class=\"entry-excerpt\">".$album1['desc']."</div>
</li>";
}
?>
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly??

Comment: The link always come up as http://vfire.sabinalcanyon.org no matter what the id really is.

Answer (score 1):

u do know that you have a single '=' for comparison when you should have 2?

Comment: I did not see that azngunit81!  After fixing that it still doesn't work but Thank you for finding that though.

Comment: can you please add the var_dump of the $album1 array (or a print_r) ..this will tell us if its fetching the right items.

Comment: I have done so and the ids are correct and all should be working

Comment: you have a semi colon; after the parenthese of the if statement so the {} are skipped

Comment: That is the issue.  I found it a little while ago and forgot to update here.  But thank you so much for the help.